# How to read comma separated integer inputs in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class usingDelimiters
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner dis=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b,c;
        a=dis.nextInt();
        b=dis.nextInt();
        c=dis.nextInt();
        System.out.println("a="+a);
        System.out.println("b="+b);
        System.out.println("c="+c);
    }
}
```

This program is working fine when my input is 1 2 3 (separated by space)
But, how to modify my program when my input is 1,2,3 (separated by commas)

Comment: comma separated integers == comma separated values == CSV == use OpenCSV? By hand is OK if it's toy code, but for serious work, consider using OpenCSV.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use the nextLine method to read a String and use the method split to separate by comma like this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner dis=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b,c;
        String line;
        String[] lineVector;

        line = dis.nextLine(); //read 1,2,3

        //separate all values by comma
        lineVector = line.split(",");

        //parsing the values to Integer
        a=Integer.parseInt(lineVector[0]);
        b=Integer.parseInt(lineVector[1]);
        c=Integer.parseInt(lineVector[2]);

        System.out.println("a="+a);
        System.out.println("b="+b);
        System.out.println("c="+c);
    }
```

This method will be work with 3 values separated by comma only.

If you need change the quantity of values may you use an loop to get the values from the vector.

Answer (score 19):

You can use a delimiter for non-numerical items, which will mark any non-digit as delimiter.

Such as:

```
dis.useDelimiter("\\D");
```

The `useDelimiter` method takes a `Pattern` or the `String` representation of a `Pattern`.

Full example:

```
Scanner dis=new Scanner(System.in);
dis.useDelimiter("\\D");
int a,b,c;
a=dis.nextInt();
b=dis.nextInt();
c=dis.nextInt();
System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
dis.close();
```

**Inputs (either or)**

- `1,2,3`
- `1 2 3`

**Output**

```
1 2 3
```

**Note**

- Don't forget to `close` your `Scanner`!
- See the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for `Pattern`s for additional fun delimiting your input.