# taking multiple inputs in a specific format as a single input in java

Tags: java, c, syntax

I have been using the scanner so far for taking inputs in java but what i need for this particular task is setting values for 4 variables with a single line input i.e.  07:05:45PM

The C equivalent solution for this particular solution is as follows:

```
scanf("%d:%d:%d%s", &hh, &mm, &ss, t12) ;
```

I am looking for the java equivalent of this code.

Comment: "what i need for this particular task is setting values for 4 variables with a single line input" -- **Why?**

Comment: Can't you take the input in a string variable and then use `split` or `substring` functions to suit your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Scanner` instance by setting to it a delimiter such as `"\\s*:\\s*"`.

It could give this code :

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("07:05:45PM").useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*");

int hours = s.nextInt();
int minutes = s.nextInt();
String secondAndMeridiem = s.next();
int seconds = Integer.valueOf(secondAndMeridiem.substring(0, 2));
String meridiem = secondAndMeridiem.substring(2, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try delimiter option in scanner, but it will not support multiple delimiters together. So it will not support your requirement of ""%d:%d:%d%s"" fully.

Please have a look at

[How to read comma separated integer inputs in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936218/how-to-read-comma-separated-integer-inputs-in-java)

Just curious to know, why don't you look at the SimpleDateFormatter to parse the single string and get hour, minutes, seconds

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could get is this but this would work only if there was some delimiter between 45 and PM in `07:05:45PM` like `07:05:45 PM`. Otherwise, the input needs to be taken as String and parsed.

```
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int hh, mm, ss;
  String t12;
  scanner.useDelimiter("[:\n ]");
  hh = scanner.nextInt();
  mm = scanner.nextInt();
  ss = scanner.nextInt();
  t12 = scanner.next();
  System.out.println(hh);
  System.out.println(mm);
  System.out.println(ss);
  System.out.println(t12);
}
```